# Proving language is not regular using pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, pumping-lemma

Show that the language

$L =$$\left \{ a^{n!} : n\geq 1 \right \}$ is not regular using pumping lemma

My solution is :

Suppose L is regular

There exist some pumping length for L, let it be "m"

We don't know the value of m but whatever it is we can always choose n = m.

Then from the pumping lemma there exists $x, y, z \in Σ^{∗}$ such that w = xyz , |xy| ≤ m and |y| ≥ 1.

$w_{i} = xy^{i}z$

y must contain entirely of a's

suppose $|y|=k$

the string obtained by i = 1 is,

w = $a^{m!+k}$

---

Now after this i'm stuck because how can i prove $m!+k$ cannot be accepted by the language

also if i chose i = 0 then also i'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

Pick $i$ such that $m! + ik \neq h!$ for some $h$, and you are done. In particular, if $i=1$, then $m! + k \leq m! + m \neq (m+1)!$.

Your proof otherwise looks good!

Comment: but how can we pick k? are we allowed to pick k anywhere between $1 \leq k \leq m$ that helps in contradiction?

Comment: i read [Introduction of formal languages and Automata by peter linz](https://gateoverflow.in/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=7652287032223676387) and we cannot choose the decomposition of string. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I misread your proof a little. You want to select $i$ appropriately. See my edit.

Comment: Suppose L is regular
There exist some pumping length for L, let it be "m"

We don't know the value of m but whatever it is we can always choose n = m.

Then from the pumping lemma there exists $x, y, z \in Σ^{∗}$ such that w = xyz , |xy| ≤ m and |y| ≥ 1.

$w_{i} = xy^{i}z$

 y must contain entirely of a's

suppose $|y|=k$

the string obtained by i = 1 is,

w = $a^{m!+k}$
we know that k $\geq$1 

so  if 1 $\leq$ k $\leq$ m

$m!$ $<$ $(m! + k)$ $<$ $(m+1)!$ 

hence we can say that $a^{m!+k}$ $\notin L$
Hence our assumption of L being regular was wrong and L is not regular.

Comment: can you confirm this?

Comment: Pick $i=2$. Note that for $i=1$, $y^{i} = y$.